# Proving algebraicity of compact Riemann surfaces without Chow's theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

I am trying to write a report for a complex analysis class where I prove Riemann-Roch and apply it to prove algebraicity of compact Riemann surfaces. While writing this, I found that Riemann-Roch quite nicely yields a very ample line bundle and hence a holomorphic embedding into projective space. However, it was not so obvious to me why the image of a holomorphic embedding $f: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{CP}^N$ (for $X$ a compact Riemann surface) is actually an algebraic variety.

The resources I have consulted tend to resolve this either by not mentioning algebraicity (as Forster does) or appealing to Chow's theorem (as Griffiths and Harris does). Also, Miranda does a strange thing where an "algebraic curve" is not the zero set of polynomials, but a Riemann surface whose meromorphic functions separate points and tangents. I find the algebraicity of compact Riemann surfaces to be a very striking and beautiful fact, but Chow's theorem is quite advanced for what I am intending this report to be, and I don't believe I can include a proof of it. Furthermore, Chow's theorem applies very generally to any analytic subvariety of $\mathbb{CP}^N$. As I am only interested in the case of $\dim X = 1$, I was wondering if a more elementary argument for algebraicity is out there.

In attempting to find such an argument, I tried to compute the Zariski closure of $im(f)$ and use that as a candidate, but I was not able to show equality. Specifically, I wrote $f$ as $x \mapsto [f_0(x) : \dots : f_N(x)]$. Given that the transcendence degree of the field of meromorphic functions $\mathcal M(X)$ over $\mathbb C$ is $1$, we can ensure that the map $\mathbb C[x_0, \dots, x_N] \longrightarrow \mathcal{M}(X)$ sending $x_i \mapsto f_i$ has a nontrival kernel $\mathfrak p$ of height $n$. As such, letting $Z(\mathfrak p)$ be the variety in $\mathbb{CP}^N$ defined by $\mathfrak p$, we can show that $im(f) \subseteq Z(\mathfrak p)$. By dimension considerations, I would expect to have equality $im(f) = Z(\mathfrak p)$, but it's not at all obvious to me why the reverse inclusion must hold. $Z(\mathfrak p)$ will be the Zariski closure of $im(f)$, so what I'm asking is of course tantamount to showing that $im(f)$ is Zariski closed.

I was also recommended to try using Riemann-Roch to get a finite covering $X \longrightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$ and use this to prove algebraicity. I suspect that I am to analyze the associated map on sheaves of holomorphic functions $f^*: \mathcal O_{\mathbb{CP}^1} \longrightarrow \mathcal O_X$ and exploit finiteness as well as the fact that $\mathcal O_{\mathbb{CP}^1}$ is the analytification of an algebraic sheaf. But this too is not clear to me.

Is there any known elementary argument I can use?

Answer (score 13):

Given an embedding $X\to \Bbb P^n$, it's possible to construct polynomial equations for the image.

> **Theorem** (Narasimhan 9.6.2): Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface and $f$, a nonconstant meromorphic function on $X$. Then, there exists an integer $p>0$ with the following property:
>
> For any $F$ meromorphic on $X$, there exist rational functions $a_1,\dots,a_p$ (in one variable) such that $$(F(x))^p+a_1(f(x))(F(x))^{p-1}+\cdots+a_p(f(x))=0 \quad \text{on } X.$$

The idea of the proof is that the map $f:X\to\Bbb P^1$ is a covering map with fibers of constant size $p$ over some set $U\subset \Bbb P^1$ with finite complement in $\Bbb P^1$. Let $a_k(z)$ be the $k^{th}$ elementary symmetric polynomial in the values of $F$ along the $p$ points in $f^{-1}(z)$. Then the $a_k(z)$ are meromorphic functions on $\Bbb P^1$ and hence rational, and the relation above holds everywhere by continuity.

Letting $f$ and $F$ vary among the meromorphic functions you used to embed $X$ in $\Bbb P^n$, after clearing denominators you get polynomial equations for the image. Alternatively, a little extra work with the above result shows that the field of meromorphic functions on $X$ is a finitely generated field of transcendence degree one over $\Bbb C$, which is exactly an algebraic function field. By the standard theory of such objects, it's equivalent to a smooth projective curve over $\Bbb C$ where the (closed) points correspond to (nontrivial) discrete valuations trivial on $\Bbb C$, and this correspondence between points and valuations *also* holds on the Riemann surface side.

---

*Narasimhan, Raghavan; Nievergelt, Yves*, Complex analysis in one variable., Boston, MA: Birkhäuser. xiv, 381 p. (2001). [ZBL1009.30001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1009.30001).

Comment: I think one can also prove the above theorem by dimension counting.  If $F, f$ obey no algebraic relations then the space of polynomial combinations of $F,f$ of degree at most $d$ gives rise to a divisor of degree $O(d)$ whose space of sections has dimension growing at least quadratically in $d$, but from Riemann-Roch (or just by inspecting Laurent expansions around each pole and using Liouville's theorem) this dimension can only grow linearly in $d$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the response! If I understand correctly, by varying $f$ and $F$ among the $f_i$ defining the embedding into $\mathbb P^N$ we can show that $\mathbb C(f_0, \dots, f_N)$ is finite over $\mathbb C(f_0)$ and hence has transcendence degree $1$ over $\mathbb C$. I can see why this yields a set of polynomials on which $X$ vanishes, but I'm having trouble seeing why any point which vanishes on said polynomials must be in the image of the embedding. Am I missing a part of this argument?
Also @TerryTao I think that's similar to the argument Miranda gives in Prop VI.1.17.

Comment: Fair enough, the construction I gave may end up giving a polynomial that is too large and contains some components beyond $X$.  But the construction given in the above post should give $X$ on the nose, because it is a degree $k$ relation and the fibers of $X$ generically have size $k$.

Comment: @Ktravler This proof is quite slick. While I understand how this generates equations which $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ must satisfy, is it clear that the intersection of the zero loci of these equations gives exactly $X$?